# Re-init tinyMCE

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I have modal, which is started with button. Then this code is executed, where "form" variable contains also textarea.tinymce

```
$(".modal-body").empty();
....
var form = ....
...
$(".modal-body").append(form);
 tinyMCE.init({
    mode: "specific_textareas",
    editor_selector: "tinymce",
    height : "350"
});
```

But when I close and reopen modal, the textarea won`t become tinymce, but normal textarea. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Both `mode` and `editor_selector` are options from TinyMCE 3. In TinyMCE 5 you should use the `selector` option which is documented here:
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/integration-and-setup/#selector

If that doesn't fix the problem then you will need to provide more information about how you are hiding and showing the modal. If you are hiding it with CSS then it should be possible to load TinyMCE however if you are removing it from the DOM then TinyMCE won't work.